# dask.delayed. defined variable in one cell of Jupyter notebook not working in any other

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dask

this is my first post on stackoverflow and I hope to have chosen the right category. So here is my problem:

In order to get to know [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) I decided to get started with this [tutorial](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial)!

After creating the conda environment and running the python script like it was suggested in README.md, I tried the following lines:

```py
from time import sleep
from dask import delayed

def inc(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x + 1

def add(x, y):
    sleep(1)
    return x + y
```

I used another cell in the Jupyter notebook to do

```py
x = delayed(inc)(1)
y = delayed(inc)(2)
z = delayed(add)(x, y)
```

If I now use the same cell for

```py
z.compute()
```

I get the correct result. But if I do this in yet another cell, I get a

> NameError: name 'z' is not defined

I have no idea why this happens and did not find any clue elsewhere. Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.
sgr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in jupyter (or ipykernel) which means that variables defined in a cell with `%%time` do not survive the cell. Either downgrade, or re-run the code without timing.

ref https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/issues/85

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer. That was it!